# Entity Framework - Accepting Object Changes in Win Form App (Algorithm)

Tags: .net, algorithm, entity-framework

All,

I am trying to think of a way (algorithm) in which to pass a list of entity objects to a Form in my UI (Win Form Application) for editing (say in a Grid - which is irrelevant for this - it's the concept I want to establish).  The form, say it is named FormEdit, has an OK, Cancel, and Apply button.

My entity has the following hierarchy for examples sake:

```
Class Entity1
   ...
   Entity2List As EntityCollection(Of Entity2)
   ...
End Class 

Class Entity2
    ...
    SomeValue As String   ' This would be a field in my entity mapping to the database
    ...
```

It is the Entity2List I want to edit in FormEdit.

The FormEdit will be triggered from my main form, which will pass in the Entity2List.  There will be a Save button in the main form which will do context.SaveChanges().  The main form will do the initial loading.

On clicking OK, any changes will be persisted and the FormEdit closes.
On clicking Apply, any changes should be persisted.
On clicking Cancel, I want to disregard any edits that have been made in FormEdit and close it so Entity1.Entity2List to it's inital state when the FormEdit was loaded (unless Apply was clicked - see Scenarios below).

Now, I can go into FormEdit a number of times, so any changes made needs to be in the scope of that form.  So suppose I do the following, given the following initial state:

There is a single record/row/object in Entity1.
Entity1.Entity2List contains 2 records/rows/objects with the following:

```
Record1:  SomeValue = 33
Record2:  SomeValue = 10
```

**Scenario 1**

1. Start Application - entities loaded into main form.
2. Click on an Edit button to trigger display of FormEdit which takes Entity1(Instance).Entity2List as a parameter.
3. Add a new row to the grid, which in turn adds a row to Entity1.Entity2List.
4. Modify Record1, change SomeValue from 33 to 100.
5. Click on Cancel.  This should return Entity1.Entity2List to it's inital state.

**Scenario 2**

1. Start Application - entities loaded into main form.
2. Click on an Edit button to trigger display of FormEdit which takes Entity1(Instance).Entity2List as a parameter.
3. Modify Record1, change SomeValue from 33 to 100.
4. Click on Apply.
5. Modify Record1, change SomeValue from 100 to -9.
6. Click on Cancel.  This will revert the changed made in Step 5.  The change made in Step 3 will be remembered as Apply was clicked.

I need some sort of mechanism for tracking changes like this.  When OK/Apply is clicked the changes are made to the objects on my Context.

Are there any approaches to doing this?  All ideas and suggestions welcome.

Cheers,

Andez

Comment: Using entity framework? Ok/Apply : `context.SaveChanges();`. Cancel : `context.Dispose();`.

Comment: I dont think I want to dispose of the context as all of my changes are on it.  There is an overall save outside of the FormEdit.  I didn't make this clear so I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening a second form in order to edit a collection on a single entity that appears in a list on your first form then I would consider using a new context each time for FormEdit. If the Entity2 collection of each entity is never displayed or interacted with on the first form then I do not see any advantage in using a single context. In fact, using a single context for both forms will [increase memory consumption as more and more enities are added to the collection, increase the chance of concurrency issues, and increase instability of your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737).

Using a second context makes it very easy to cancel changes by just calling `context.Dispose()`. Otherwise you would have to loop through all `DbEntityEntry` objects in the context change tracker and set `CurrentValues` back to `OriginalValues`, discard any new entity2 objects you may have added and change the state of any deleted entity2 objects. Apply and Ok buttons would simply need to call `context.SaveChanges()` on the separate context.

If you need to sync entity state on both forms you could look at detaching entities and adding them to the relevant context you are working on or by simply reloading the entity on form1 after form2 closes.

Comment: I totally agree.  But I think things are getting messy.  My initial thought was to have a save button in the main screen which would call context.SaveChanges().  However, if the user creates an instance of Entity1 then goes into the FormEdit.  I don't think I can edit List(Of Entity2) on another context as no change has been saved?  I had already implemented you solution in my admin screens which works great - it's just the main part of the application causing a headache.  I did implement my own solution where I have to track all changes myself which is a lot of effort.